remove duplicate nested list from json using python
{
  "acc_id": "AAA",
  "cont_id": "CCC",
  "location": [
    {
      "x": 123,
      "y": 323,
      "z": 444
    },
    {
      "x": 123,
      "y": 323,
      "z": 444
    },
    {
      "x": 123,
      "y": 323,
      "z": 444
    }
  ]
}

should become:
{
  "acc_id": "AAA",
  "cont_id": "CCC",
  "location": [
    {
      "x": 123,
      "y": 323,
      "z": 444
    }
  ]
}

Note: I have tried below code, it is not taking inner list.
unique = {each[0]: each for each in k}.values()


Is the shape of the inner list always a list of dictionaries? What if there are non-overlapping keys sometimes? ([{'a': 3}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}])

You can use recursion to remove the duplicates using a set() of visited elements:
def _unique(D):
    if isinstance(D, dict):
        for k, v in D.items():
            D[k] = _unique(v)
        return D
    elif isinstance(D, list):
        if all(isinstance(item, dict) for item in D):
            seen, res = set(), []
            for item in D:
                ts = tuple(sorted(item.items()))
                if ts not in seen:
                    seen.add(ts)
                    res.append(_unique(item))
            return res
        else:
            return D
    else:
        return D


data = {
    "acc_id": "AAA",
    "cont_id": "CCC",
    "location": [
        {"x": 123, "y": 323, "z": 444},
        {"x": 123, "y": 323, "z": 444},
        {"x": 123, "y": 323, "z": 444}
    ]
}
print(_unique(data))


Prints
{'acc_id': 'AAA', 'cont_id': 'CCC', 'location': [{'x': 123, 'y': 323, 'z': 444}]}



this worked !! Even other answer also worked though this solution took less execution time.

You can convert the items of sub-dicts into frozensets so that you can de-duplicate them as a set:
data['location'] = list(map(dict, {frozenset(d.items()) for d in data['location']}))

Demo: https://ideone.com/ybwDPJ

This might be good enough, but beware it's sensitive to the order of the items yielded by the dictionaries. If you want [{a:1, b:2}, {b:2, a:1}] to simplify, then it won't work. To fix the issue, you could pass the items() to sorted before turning them into a frozenset. list(map(dict, {frozenset(sorted(d.items())) for d in data['location']})), but that's getting confusing enough you might not want to stick with a one-liner

No, a frozenset of tuples yielded by dict.items() is orderless so no need to resort to a redundant sorting. Demo: https://ideone.com/h2SNoo

Oh, you're right, I was mixing up the order of operations when I was thinking it wasn't good enough.
